# '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:integer'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

xml can contain an element whose data type is integer and it could be empty also. I am getting the error
`'' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:integer'`

Is there a way to specify only min length for this element or something like the value of this element is optional in xsd?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

(a) define a union type that allows either an integer, or a zero-length string

(b) define a list type with an item type of `xs:integer`, with minLength=0 and maxLength=1.

Both are equivalent from the point of view of validation. (a) is more commonly seen, but in my view (b) is simpler. They will likely give different results if you are doing data typing with the schema rather than just validation, for example if you are using schema-aware XSLT or XQuery, or JAXP-style data binding.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Kay has given two possible solutions, but a third (and in some ways simpler) option is to indicate the element as `nillable`. When it is nillable, you can leave it blank and indicate it as nil using `xsi:nil="true"`.

However, if you don't have any control over the XML such that you could include `xsi:nil`, then you'd need to go with one of Michael Kay's suggestions.

Schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="n">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="count" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="count" type="xsd:integer" nillable="true" />
</xsd:schema>
```

XML:

```xml
<n xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <count xsi:nil="true" />
</n>
```

Comment: I've never seen a good reason for using `xsi:nil`. It's so ugly!